# Is there a solution to get a list of columns that rows are equal to 0?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am building a Power Bi Q&A Dashboard that shows pass or fail within specific criteria. 1 meaning Pass, 0 meaning Fail. If any of the Categories Fail, the entire row fails.

Example:

| Rep Name | Categories 1 | Categories 2 | Categories 3 | Pass/Fail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob Smith | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Tyler Jones | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

What I am looking for is a way to say, If (Pass/Fail) = 0 then list all columns have a value = 0.

In this example, I should get a result of Tyler Jones Failed in Criteria 2 & 3

What is the best way in either Dax or Mcode to do this?

Comment: Using Power Query you could merge the columns containing the categories (`Table.CombineColumns`) and then check if that new column contains a zero (`Text.Contains`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot your Category and use a CONCATENAX. Below example.

M transformation:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcspPUgjOzSzJUNJRMkTBsTrRSiGVOalFCl75eanFUHEDOI6NBQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Rep Name" = _t, #"Categories 1" = _t, #"Categories 2" = _t, #"Categories 3" = _t, #"Pass/Fail" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Rep Name", type text}, {"Categories 1", Int64.Type}, {"Categories 2", Int64.Type}, {"Categories 3", Int64.Type}, {"Pass/Fail", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Rep Name", "Pass/Fail"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Pass/Fail"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

DAX measure:

```
FailAts = CONCATENATEX(CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( 'Table (2)'[Attribute] ),'Table (2)'[Value] = 0 ), 'Table (2)'[Attribute]," ")
```

[image]

Comment: IF its ok, please mark answer as valid